# Azure Logic Apps - Inline JS Code - Load External Module

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to import an external module into an Inline Code action in Azure Logic Apps?

To prevent repeating common utility code in multiple Logic App Inline Code actions we'd like to store it in one place and reference it from multiple Logic Apps.

The [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) say that the require() function isn't supported.

I thought about storing common code in an Http enabled Azure storage account and referencing from there but I've read that the Node JS module loader doesn't (yet) support loading from http sources.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

We can load the required modules in OneDrive or from Dropbox and reference it in our logicapp.

For this we need to setup the workflow settings and make a connection to our connector to get the content that needs to be used in the code.

Below are few points that needs to be followed:

1. Under actions Add the code by selecting Execute JS Code.

> ```
> var note = "" + workflowContext.actions.Get_file_content.outputs.body;
> var posTag = note.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
> var cleanNote = {};
>
> if(posTag > 0){
>         cleanNote.tags = note.substring(posTag, note.length-1);
>         cleanNote.msg = note.substring(0,posTag-1);
>     }
> return cleanNote;
> ```

2. Check whether the content path and connection strings are added.
   [image]
3. This will access to the workflow context.

The above are the priority steps to achieve this, for more information on understanding the steps, refer to this [blog](http://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/06/be-more-productive-by-using-inline-code.html), thanks to frankysnotes for great description.

If you need any changes, you can make them according to your own requirement.